# Install / Configure SQL Server PDO driver for PHP docker image

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, pdo

I have a simple docker file, as follows:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

Normally to install drivers for Mongo or MySQL connectivity I would do so by adding something like the below to the dockerfile:

```
docker-php-ext-install mongo
```

On this occasion I want to connect my php application to a SQL Server database, and I understand the best way to do this for php 7.x is by using the PDO driver, however I am unfamiliar with how to do configure this in the dockerfile.

I've tried doing a pecl install, like adding:

```
RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

However this fails with a combination of errors that do not seem to point me in the right direction.

I'm just looking for a simple way to get this done in a dockerfile or by using docker run.

For added info, here's the error I'm getting:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/xplat.h:30:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sql.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:194: recipe for target 'conn.lo' failed
make: *** [conn.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv     && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlsrv' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Thanks all

Comment: Did you do a `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo` first?

Comment: I have tried that yes, I get the same error, please see edited main post, I have included the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have created a docker file for this exact purpose:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev 
RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
RUN docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

COPY . /var/www/html/
```

Enjoy!

Comment: how are you not at the top? great job!

Answer (score 9):

Did you get an answer to this?  I got it working with the following steps.  (The unixodbc-dev package should get you past the pecl install.)

in the Docker file:

```
RUN apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

And then you have to add some changes to php.ini to enable sqlserver.

get a local copy of php.ini and add these lines:

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

Then copy your local php.ini into the docker image (my file is in a local "config" folder).

in the Docker file:

```
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

Comment: I followed exactly your instructions, but I get the following error: `Error connecting to SQL Server: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712`. Do I need to download and integrate the files "pdo_sqlsrv.so" and "sqlsrv.so" somewhere?

Comment: have you solve this issue @chris

Comment: @MohamedRaza I have just posted my config as an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75222902/415353)

Comment: @chris okay i will check

Answer (score 1):

My docker config:

```
###############
# MSSQL support
###############
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gpg unixodbc unixodbc-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

# ------------ Install MS SQL client deps ------------ #
# adding custom MS repository
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# install SQL Server drivers and tools
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

# Debian 9 msodbcsql : https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/msodbcsql17_17.4.2.1-1_amd64.deb
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y dpkg -i msodbcsql17_17.4.2.1-1_amd64.deb

RUN apt-get -y install locales
RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen

RUN echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sqlsrv.ini
RUN echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo-sqlsrv.ini
# -------------- END MSSQL -------------------------------- #
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM php:7.4.0-apache
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev 
RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv pdo pdo_mysql
COPY index.php /var/www/html/
```

Comment: It's works fine

Comment: what is the `enter code here` suppose to be filled with?